# Spring Boot LDAP Authentication

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-boot, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to test Active Directory authentication with Spring Boot. I have an Active Directory working and I can access to it via LDAP browsers for my admin user with that user dn:

```
CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=contoso,DC=com
```

I want to use LDAP as authentication manager at my application. Simple example from docs is as follows:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .ldapAuthentication()
            .userDnPatterns("CN={0},CN=Users,DC=contoso,DC=com")
            .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
            .contextSource()
            .managerDn("CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=contoso,DC=com")
            .managerPassword("myadminpassword")
            .url("ldap://192.168.1.1:389");
}
```

First of all, should I provide admin password to connect Active Directory such a login?

Secondly, should I provide groupSearchBase and userDnPatterns and how?

Answer (score 3):

1. No. For accessing LDAP / Active Directory from your application, you should create a "browse user" in your user directory. The DN and password of the browse user should not be hardcoded, but e.g. in a configuration file of your application.
2. This mainly depends on your LDAP / AD setup. In an Active Directory, the user names are usually stored in the attribute "sAMAccountName", which is not part of the user's DN, so `userDnPatterns` will not work. Instead, provide a user search filter, e.g. `.userSearchFilter("(sAMAccountName={0})")` (most probably you will need more, but the administrator of the directory should be able to tell you that). An additional `userSearchBase` may be helpful as well. But this is all not Spring-, but LDAP specific. Again, refer to your LDAP administrator for recommended values for the possible configuration items.